# How to get char qualification in string from regexp point of view?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio

Task is simple for human eye - determine if a char is a part of a word, is special simbol or is a part of a number. And we have a string in unknown language like arabic\chinese\english or any mix of numbers/code etc. We have simple qualifiers in regexp: `\w` for word; `^\d$` for number else for other. We have an API like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch(v=vs.110).aspx) that can do half of work: `expr.IsMatch(text, position)` yet we can not word/number start index or end index out from it. Is there a vay to get from regexp start\end simbols of selected object only providing to i index of char in it? Or manual iteration back char by char and thab forvard char by char shall be implemented?

Comment: Do lookbehinds work with Match? isnt it starting from given position as if it was a new string?

Comment: The problem is to determine where word/number containing given character begins and ends.

Comment: Can you give test cases?

Comment: `<hello="red"> 123.432 <work hard>` on char index 0 we get special char; on 1 or 2 or 3...or 5 we get word with range 1 to 5; on char index  15 we get positions of "123" as a number and so on